# Get ID from URL

Tags: standardcontroller, url, id

I have a custom object, Job (`Job__c` (this is parent)), and another custom object is Job Applicant (`Job_Applicant__c` (this is child).

How do I get `ID` from the URL from `sc.getRecord().id` in the following?

```
public class Job_Application{
    public Id JobID{get;set;}
    public List<Job__c> Query{get;set;}

    public Job_Application(ApexPages.StandardController sc){

        JobID = sc.getRecord().id;
        System.debug('----Job ID ----- ' + JobID);
        fetchRecords();
    }

    public void fetchRecords(){
        Query = [SELECT Id, (SELECT id, Name, Experience__c, Qualification__c, Score__c, Spoken_Language__c, Technical__c FROM Job_Applicants__r) FROM Job__c WHERE Id =:JobID];

        System.debug('---Query Result ---- ' + Query);
    }
}
```

This is not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried simply:

`JobID = sc.getId();`

See docs [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardController_methods.htm).

This assumes that the `standardController` attribute on your page is for `Job__c` and that the URL is something like `/apex/YourPage?id=[some job id]`.

Answer (score 0):

Apexpages is a global variable that you can access from your constructor, probably your problem is the ApexPages.StandardController sc variable that you are passing as an argument in the constructor is probably being declared as null, so:

Just use the following:

```
JobID = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');
```

instead

```
JobID = sc.getRecord().id;
```

And remove `ApexPages.StandardController sc` from the parameters of your constructor, it should work now